# Display JSON Nested Objects javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to display 2 objects which has nested object.

```
const axios = require("axios").default;

async function getPeople() {
  const { data } = await axios.get(
    "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/graffixnyc/a1196cbf008e85a8e808dc60d4db7261/raw/9fd0d1a4d7846b19e52ab3551339c5b0b37cac71/people.json"
  );
  return data; // this will be the array of people objects
}

function checkinput(input) {
  if (input === undefined) throw "The input cannot be empty";
  if (typeof input !== "string") throw "The input should be a string value";
  let triminput = input.trim();
  if (triminput.length == 0) throw "The input cannot be empty space";
}



function checkemail(emailDomain) {
  checkinput(emailDomain);
  if (emailDomain.includes(".") == false) throw "No domain extension";
  let afterdot = emailDomain.substring(emailDomain.lastIndexOf("."));
  if (afterdot.length < 3) {
    throw "Domain extension length is shorter than 2 characters.";
  }
}

async function sameEmail(emailDomain) {
  let data = await getPeople();
  let user = [];
  checkemail(emailDomain);
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i]["email"].includes(emailDomain) == true) {
      user.push(data[i]);
    }
  }
  return user;
}

    const sameemail = await people.sameEmail("weebly.com");
    console.log(sameemail);
```

I keep getting output like this

```
[
  {
    id: '47caf2da-7234-4f48-9eb9-0d05ebf83a19',
    first_name: 'Abbey',
    last_name: 'Hindhaugh',
    email: 'ahindhaugha@weebly.com',
    ip_address: '246.81.174.68',
    ssn: '494-34-5306',
    date_of_birth: '10/08/1942',
    address: { home: [Object], work: [Object] }
  }
]
```

instead of `address: { home: [Object], work: [Object] }`
it should return some like this

```
[{
  id: 'cae04d34-29e9-4969-b2cd-cc1f83d8f7db',
  first_name: 'Ardenia',
  last_name: 'Biddulph',
  email: 'abiddulph2k@sogou.com',
  ip_address: '134.43.199.130',
  ssn: '708-40-1042',
  date_of_birth: '09/01/1970',
  address: {
    home: {
      street_number: '8327',
      street_name: 'Muir',
      street_suffix: 'Junction',
      city: 'Tacoma',
      state: 'WA',
      zip: '98424'
    },
    work: {
      street_number: '28',
      street_name: 'Stang',
      street_suffix: 'Park',
      city: 'Tampa',
      state: 'FL',
      zip: '33673'
    }
  }
}]
```

So I don't understand where i'm going wrong. actually i'm new to javascript so don't know where i'm making a mistake.

IGNORE
Make the code sections smaller by removal of imports, comments, code sections that are not critical. If needed make a hard choice and remove the least important code.
Then when others ask questions, answer the questions inline but also update your original post with the details. Then you might be able to add more code to your original post.
I realize that this solution is not ideal, however it provides with practical steps. I hope others find it useful.

Comment: You need to [serialize it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) from an object to a string.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/dir

Comment: Convert it to a JSON string: `console.log(JSON.stringify(sameemail, null ,3));` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify